# How to block Unicode characters from a text box input?

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, unicode

I want to block users from entering Unicode characters into any of the text boxes on a specific form on an web page. Is there a regular expression validation check I can use with jQuery to achieve this?

Comment: Please only use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag when the question is about the jQuery Validate plugin.

Comment: If you mean only printable ASCII characters: `/^[\u0021-\u007e]*$/`.

Comment: HTML and JavaScript use Unicode. I think you mean you want a subset of Unicode characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `[\x20-\x7E]` regex to allow any [ASCII characters](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII-Table-wide.svg) between a space and the tilde symbol, like this:

```
$("#Your_Form_Id").submit(function() {
    var input_value = $("#Your_Text_Box_Id").val();
    var pattern = /^[\x20-\x7E]*$/;
    if(!pattern.test(input_value)) {
        $("#Your_Text_Box_Id").after('<span class="error">Only printable ASCII is allowed.</span>');
    }
});
```